# Trying to understand Pine Script's Security() function and then convert it to Python

Tags: python, pine-script

I am new to Python and much more to Pine Script. My goal is to understand how the Security() function works.

I have the following code written in Pine Script.

```
//@version=3
strategy(title = "Simple Lookahead", shorttitle = "SL", overlay = true, 
  pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value = 10, calc_on_every_tick=false)
multip      = input(defval = 2,    title = "Multiplier")
lenPeriod    = input(defval = 2, title = "Period", minval = 1)
resol    = isdaily?  tostring(interval*multip,"###D") : isintraday ? tostring(interval*multip,"####") : '60'
maximo = security(tickerid, resol, high, gaps=barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(maximo, color = yellow)
```

In this code, through the Security() function, I try to obtain the maximum values in another period of time. When running this script I notice that it does not get the expected values. That is, the chart shows (orange arrow) that the maximum between the candlestick indicated by the arrow and the purple candlestick should not be the one drawn by the yellow line. Logically the maximum between both Highs is indicated by the purple arrow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd1z6.png)

Maybe I don't get enough understanding of the Security() function since the documentation I found has little information on how it works internally.
What would I be interpreting incorrectly? I just need to understand how Security() works, then I'll see how I translate it into Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've removed [tag:security] from the tags; that has been defined differently than a security in finance.

Comment: It takes data from another symbol and maps it into bars of the current symbol.

Comment: @starr-lucky thanks for commenting, but if lookahead is on, as in this case, it maps with timeframe, is it so? I still can't understand how it calculates the new timeframe, or where can I get the source code of the security() function to study it in depth?